# How to split string into multiple substrings enclosed with [ ] and where delimiter is also found within the substring?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**TLDR;**

In Javascript, how do I split this string `[test,string,0,5,bob,0,1],[age,number,1,100,20,0,1], [male,const,0,0,yes,200,1]` into an array of substrings each bounded by `[]`:

`[test,string,0,5,bob,0,1]`, `[age,number,1,100,20,0,1]`, `[male,const,0,0,yes,200,1]`

**Context:**

I need to process lines from a config file into an array, using Node JS.
A line is a string of the form:

```
someID,[test,string,0,5,bob,0,1],[age,number,1,100,20,0,1],[male,const,0,0,yes,200,1]
```

This needs to end up as an element in an array:

```
var config = [
// One line from the config file:
['someID', ['test','string',0,5,'bob',0,1],[12,'number',1,100,20,0,1],['male','const',0,0,'yes',200,1]],

// more elements each representing a line...
];
```

I can get the first item off the config line, 'someID' above, using `line.split(',',1)[0]` but how do I separate the rest of the string into sub elements bound by `[` and `]`  ?

I've tried JS string.match() :

```
var elements = str.match(/\[(.*)\]/g);
```

but I get a single string with

```
"[test,string,0,5,bob,0,1],[age,number,1,100,20,0,1], [male,const,0,0,yes,200,1]"
```

(I realise this is because it's only matching against the first `[` and last `]` and not processing everything in between)

rather than an array with separate strings:

```
"[test,string,0,5,bob,0,1]",
"[age,number,1,100,20,0,1]",
"[male,const,0,0,yes,200,1]",
```

JS .split(',') obviously takes every single comma into account and splits on all of them rather than just the commas outside the `[]`. I think solution will be a regex? Thanks.

Comment: If the space in `...0,1], [ma...` is a typo then just split on `],[`, otherwise... `.split()` "understands" regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach using `str.match(/\[(.*)\]/g)` is very good, it just needs a little adjustment. Instead of using `.*` which will match every character you should use `[^\]]` to match every character except a closing bracket.

```js
const str = "someID,[test,string,0,5,bob,0,1],[age,number,1,100,20,0,1],[male,const,0,0,yes,200,1]";

console.log(str.match(/\[[^\]]+\]/g))
```

- `\[` Match an opening bracket
- `[^]` Match all characters not in this set
- `[^\]]` Match all characters execpt `]`
- `[^\]]+` Match one ore more charcters that are not `]`
- `\]` Match a closing bracket